# Assign a variable in PHP based on HTML select option and insert result to a database table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I'm running the following queries to retrieve info from the timesheetlogin table.

```
$clientlist = db_select("SELECT * FROM timesheetlogin WHERE type='client' ORDER BY company DESC");
$candlist = db_select("SELECT * FROM timesheetlogin WHERE type='cand' ORDER BY name DESC");
```

This info is displayed in a form on the front-end.

```
<select name="client" id="client">
<?php 
    foreach($clientlist as $key => $value) {
            $company = $clientlist[$key]["company"];
            $name = " (" . $clientlist[$key]["name"] . ")";
            echo '<option value="'. $company .'">'. $company . $name .' </option>';
            $clientid = $clientlist[$key]["id"];
                    }
                ?>  
</select><br />
```

So the form has lots of blank fields that I haven't shown, with just the client and candidate name being chosen from a dropdown.

Finally I'd like to insert the entry to the database:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $clientid = db_quote($_POST['client']);
    $candid = db_quote($_POST['cand']);
```

Here is the SQL

```
db_query("INSERT INTO timesheets (clientid, candid, weekending, department, orderno, basicpay, basiccharge, otpay, otcharge, ot2pay, ot2charge, status, hue, huc) VALUES ('$client', '$cand', '$week_ending', '$department', '$order_no', '$basic_pay', '$basic_charge', '$ot_pay', '$ot_charge', '$ot2_pay', '$ot2_charge', '$status', '$hue', '$huc')");
```

The problem I have is I need to pass the id's associated with `$_POST['client']` and `$_POST['cand']` NOT the strings that are currently in the option fields.

My initial thoughts are to do something like this to check the 'client' field and query the database to get the value of the id:

```
if (isset($_POST['client'])) {
    //code
}
```

That seems messy though. I have already queried the db and looped through the `$clientlist` array, so the ids are available in that loop. Is there a way to assign the `$clientid` variable based on what the user chooses from the select box?

Thanks

Comment: you should use the client ID and cand ID as option values in the HTML form. That would automatically solve your issue.

Comment: @Burki I cant have the id's displayed on the front end for usability reasons. The user must chosse from a list of client names

Comment: the id would not be displayed, it would be the value of the option in the dropdown menu and would be the value submitted by the form

Comment: do it like this: `<option value="[someID]">[SomeReadableText]</option>`

Comment: @Burki Ah that makes sense, I knew there must have been a simple solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put ids like this :

```
$clientid = $clientlist[$key]["id"];
echo '<option value="'.$clientid.'">'. $company . $name .' </option>';
```

Comment: Just to confirm `$client = db_quote($_POST['client']);` targets the form field with a name of 'client' and the value property is stored in the variable. I have set my input fields up like this `<input name="order_no" type="text" id="order_no" value="" />`. Do I need to assign the value here, or does it get that from the user input? What would get stored in `$order_no = db_quote($_POST['order_no']);`?

Comment: Yes you need to put value here `value="" `